# XSLT mode not being triggered

Tags: xml, xslt, mode

I'm trying to use **xslt** template matching combined with the **mode** functionality to run a particular template depending on a condition. In this case whether or not `admin` is set to `true`.

```
<xsl:template match="*[//Properties[@Admin='true']]" mode="admin">
    <!-- i get here -->
    <apply-templates select="self::node()[not(../PersonalisedErrorInstance)]" mode="personalisation"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[//Properties[@Admin='false']]" mode="admin">
    <apply-templates select="self::node()" mode="personalisation"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="personalisation">
    <!-- never get here -->
```

For some reason i never seem to hit the personalisation template match, regardless of whether `admin` is `true` or `false`. Is there something blatantly obvious that i'm doing wrong?

I've tried changing `self::node()` to `*` so i'm not sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: You have forgotten the leading `xsl:` in the *apply-templates*... `<xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()" mode="personalisation"/>` should work properly, I guess.

Comment: @potame sigh... lol i've been staring at it for hours. thanks! *shoots self*

Answer (score 0):

`*` means any child entity and can not replace `self::node()`.

If you would provide your source XML we may find your problem. May be your current node has an sibling instance `PersonalisedErrorInstance`.

best regards
Majo